# Custom JSON serialization of nested objects with json4s

Tags: json, scala, serialization, json4s

I have the following structure:

```
    sealed trait BooleanExpression extends Serializable {
        def value: Boolean
    }

    case object True extends BooleanExpression with Serializable {
      val value: Boolean = true
    }

    case object False extends BooleanExpression with Serializable {
      val value: Boolean = false
    }

    case class Not(e: BooleanExpression) extends BooleanExpression with Serializable {
      val value = !e.value
    }
```

And I'd like to serialize the **Not class** with the help of **Json4s custom serializer** (my implementation):

```
    object NotSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Not](format => ( {
         //deserialize      
         case JObject(
          JField("e", null) ::
            Nil
          ) => Not(null)
        }, {
          //serialize
          case not: Not => JObject(
              JField("not", JBool(not.e.value))
              )
        }))
```

Main class looks as follows:

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val formats: Formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + NotSerializer

  val not = Not(Not(Not(False)))

  println(writePretty(not))
}
```

The class is serialized as follows:

```
    {
      "not" : true
    }
```

What I am expecting to see is :

```
{
  "not" : {
    "not" : {
      "not" : {true}
    }
  }
}
```

Can't find the bug. What am I doing wrong?

Would be much appreciated for any help.

**I have updated** the `NotSerializer`class - `case bE:BooleanExpression` part.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're not serializing a boolean, you're serializing a boolean expression. So you shouldn't be casting it to a boolean. Are you sure this is the most recent version of your code?

Comment: @RobinGreen yes, you are right. I have uploaded the latest version of my code. Removed cast to Boolean, but now I am getting another output. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serialising the value, you need to serialise the contained expression. So don't create a `JBool` - instead, call `Extraction.decompose` - and don't call `.value`, because that evaluates the Boolean expression.